# Cant get mysql query working

Tags: php, mysql, photo

ok I have these two functions in my functions file for my site they are there too move files names to my database to pull in images this is the query thats not working

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn){
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' .substr(md5(time()), 0, 10). '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($file_path) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
}



function portfolio_image($user_id, $file_temps, $file_extns ){
    $file_paths = 'images/portfolio/' .substr(md5(time()), 0, 9). '.' . $file_extns;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temps, $file_paths);
    mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `image` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($file_paths) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);

}
```

the forms

```
<textarea name="last_name" placeholder="surname" class="name"><?php echo $user_data['last_name'] ?></textarea> <br>

<input class="proupload" type="file" name="profile"><input class="profilepicup" type="submit" value="Upload">

    <? if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){
     if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name'])=== true){
            echo "<p> please choose a file </p>";
     } else {
        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

        $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

        if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn );
        } else {
            echo '<p>Incorrect file type.</p>';

            }
            }
     }
 ?>



<form action= "portfolioupload.php" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input class="proupload" type="file" name="profile"><input class="profilepicup" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form> 


        <?php if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){
     if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name'])=== true){
            echo "<p> please choose a file </p>";
     } else {
        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

        $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

        if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                portfolio_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn );
        } else {
            echo '<p>Incorrect file type.</p>';

            }
            }
     }


?>
```

I've put these queries on separate pages and they work php and mysql seems not not want to work with two image uploads on one page which is annoying as i need an profile upload bit and a portfolio image as well, is this even possible or am i going to have to have each image upload on separate pages :/

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Did you post the same code twice? I see no difference between the two querys. Do you get any error when executing the query?

Comment: @LorenzoR one sets portfolis, one sets profile.

Comment: same query only diffrence is the table.

Comment: Try `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` to display errors.

Comment: @matzone may have the right answer

Comment: Probably a data truncation error? The columns may have different sizes (yes, even an int can have a size, that's why there are bigint, etc).

Comment: One of your queries uses the variable `$file_paths` (plural), the other uses `$file_path` (singular). Are there really two variables, or is one a typo?

Comment: there different variables as they are uploading different images though i may be able to use the same query not sure :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you have one var $file_path ..

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `portfolios` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($file_path) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
```

Or maybe you have $file_path and $file_paths ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple error handling with `or die(mysql_error())` and be done with it.

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($file_path) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id))or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT**

Ok, just open plain php file, connect to db and just run this query

```
 mysql_query ("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = 'test' WHERE `user_id` = '1')or die(mysql_error());
```

And check if your db is updated, if not, you WILL get a readable error.

Comment: I have tried or die and its still not doing the query it should be, my table is still blank on the field portfolio

Comment: it should give your an error. check the error message and tell me. @iamgavin

Comment: that works so now im really confused why it wont work within my function file

Comment: @iamgavin ok, I hope you do it now, cause, am about to sleep in 10 minutes

Comment: its up now for you, if you can help you will be a god send

Comment: @iamgavin honesly, I am more confused that before. You have changed the code completely. And, you have lots of semantics errors. Before it was about updating records, now it is about uploading image

Comment: btw: `<input class="proupload" type="file" name="profile"><input class="profilepicup" type="submit" value="Upload">` is error. You can not nest input tag inside another input tag